# Problemas com posicionamneto com colunas no Bootstrap 3

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, less

Estou com um problema de posicionamento com as grids do bootstrap estou fazendo uma loja virtual onde o layout tem que ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem com minha codificação ele ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que nessa imagem os vinhos não formam as três colunas e ficam um em baixo do outro segue meu código:

**O HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center title-category">Os melhores vinhos você encontra aqui</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 categories">
            <ul class="list-unstyled filter-category">
                <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho tinto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho branco</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category">Espumante</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho do porto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">filtros</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <ul class="gallery list-unstyled">
                <li class="gallery-list">
                    <img src="images/vinho-gallary.png" class="wine-gallary"/>
                    <!--<div class="shop text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="hover-shop">comprar</a>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="description-wine">Vinho tinto Touriga</p>
                        <p class="price">R$ 150,00</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="gallery list-unstyled">
                <li class="gallery-list">
                    <img src="images/vinho-gallary.png" class="wine-gallary"/>
                    <div class="shop text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="hover-shop">comprar</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="description-wine">Vinho tinto Touriga</p>
                        <p class="price">R$ 150,00</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="gallery list-unstyled">
                <li class="gallery-list">
                    <img src="images/vinho-gallary.png" class="wine-gallary"/>
                    <div class="shop text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="hover-shop">comprar</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="description-wine">Vinho tinto Touriga</p>
                        <p class="price">R$ 150,00</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**O CSS:**

```
.title-category{
    font: italic 400 2em @font-family-serif;
}

.categories{
    font-size: 1.5em;


    .filter-category{
        background-color: @lightGray;

        .category{
            padding: 20px 40px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: @black;
            display: block;
        }

        :hover{
            background-color: @gold;
        }
    }
}

.gallery{
    padding-top: 50px;

    .gallery-list{
        display: table;

        .wine-gallary{
            background-color: @gray;
            padding: 25px 85px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .hover-shop{
            background-color: @gold;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        .description-wine{
            font: italic 400 1.5em @font-family-serif;
        }

        .price{
            color: @gold;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }
    }
}
```

Observação: Estou usando less a pagina esta toda correta somente a parte dos vinhos que esta "zuada" vale lembrar que na versão mobile eles tem que ficar um em baixo do outro mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa, tente dar uma olhada a mais nesse link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid ele mostra como trabalhar com a estrutura do bootstrap, pelo próprio bootstrap. A seguir, tenta essa estrutura abaixo: 
...

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 categories">
  <ul class="list-unstyled filter-category">
   <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho tinto</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho branco</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="category">Espumante</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="category">Vinho do porto</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div> ... filtros aqui ....</div>
  <ul>
   <li> ... lista com produtos ....</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Agora consegui postar aqui uhauha

Answer (score 2):

Tudo indica que o problema está nos tamanhos das colunas do seu grid. A largura sem deve totalizar 12, se ultrapassar irá haver quebra de linha.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 categories">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Somando as larguras das colunhas `col-sm-N`: 4 + 8 + 8 = 20
Como é mais que 12, haverá quebra de linha e o layout não ficará como esperado.

Ajuste para algo assim, deve funcionar.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 categories">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```